# Как сравнить столбцы pandas, лежащие в списке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть [датасет по голосованию в ООН](https://www.kaggle.com/unitednations/general-assembly/downloads/general-assembly.zip/1) (нужный датасет - votes). Надо сравнить, сколько раз одинаково голосовали Индия и Вьетнам начиная с 46 ассамблеи.

Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('votes.csv', sep = ",")
df
india =[]
india.append(df[(df['state_name']=='India') & (df['assembly_session']>45)])
vietnam = []
vietnam.append(df[(df['state_name']=='Vietnam') & (df['assembly_session']>45)])
india_vietnam = []
for row in india:
    if [(df['resolution']==vietnam[df['resolution']]) & (df['vote']==vietnam[df['vote']])]:
        india_vietnam.append(row)
```

Соответственно в последней части следующая ошибка

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series

Как исправить?

Comment: Вы бы нужный датасет выложили так, чтобы для его скачивания не понадобилось заводить аккаунты и проходить регистрацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работая с Pandas старайтесь избегать использование циклов:

```
In [26]: india = df.query("assembly_session >= 46 and state_name == 'India'")

In [27]: vietnam = df.query("assembly_session >= 46 and state_name == 'Vietnam'")

In [28]: res = india.merge(vietnam, on=["assembly_session", "vote_id", "resolution", "vote"])

In [29]: len(res)
Out[29]: 1434
```